# Berlekamp-Massey algorithm: case when sequence length is less than double the length of the LFSR

Tags: cryptanalysis, linear-cryptanalysis, lfsr

Suppose that we have a sequence of $N$ digits which is produced by a Linear Feedback Shift Register ([LFSR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LFSR)) and the shortest such LFSR is of length $L$. A very important tool in cryptanalysis of stream ciphers (among many other things) is the [Berlekamp-Massey algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp-Massey_algorithm); if $2L\leq N$, this algorithm will produce the *unique* shortest LFSR of length $L$ that generates the given sequence.

I just knew this as a fact but never really gave a look at the algorithm. Now I'm reading [the paper](http://unina.stidue.net/Universita%27%20di%20Genova/MoraF/MaterialeCTC/massey.pdf) by Massey that presents the algorithm and I was kind of surprised to realize that the algorithm returns a desired LFSR in any case, even if $2L>N$, however in that case we don't have a *unique* LFSR that generates the sequence, but $2L-N$ of them (in the binary case).

So why do we always refer to the Berlekamp-Massey algorithm only for the case when $2L\leq N$? Practically speaking, what kind of lengths $L$ do we use in cryptosystems, and can the algorithm be used when $2L>N$ and $N$ is "reasonably" close to $2L$? Or is the algorithm useless in that case regardless?

Comment: Due to my low reputation I couldn't add the non-existing tags "LFSR", maybe it makes sense that somebody does that..

Comment: Agreed, LFSR's probably merit a tag for themselves since there's a lot to be said about them. I added it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Berlekamp-Massey algorithm find the *shortest* LFSR that can produce the given sequence.
Formally, if the sequence has $n$ elements $S_0, S_1, \ldots, S_{n-1}$, then the 
algorithm finds $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_t$ such that for 
$i = t, t+1, \ldots, {n-1}$, the following equation holds:
$$
S_{i} +S_{i-1}\lambda_{1} + S_{i-2}\lambda_2 + \cdots + S_{i-t}\lambda_t = 0,
\tag{1}
$$
that is,
$$S_i = -\bigr(S_{i-1}\lambda_{1} + S_{i-2}\lambda_2 + \cdots + S_{i-t}\lambda_t
\bigr).
\tag{2}$$
Note that for $i=t$, we have
$$S_{t} = -\bigr(S_{t-1}\lambda_{1} + S_{t-2}\lambda_2 + \cdots + S_{0}\lambda_t
\bigr)\tag{3}$$
The idea is that the initial loading of the LFSR is $(S_0, S_1, \ldots, S_{t-1})$, 
and the *weighted sum* of the LFSR contents stated in $(3)$ is fed back
into the right end of the shift register as the LFSR contents shift one place
to the left. Thus, the new state of the LFSR is $(S_1, S_2,\ldots, S_{t-1}, S_t)$. In later clock cycles,
the LFSR will contain $(S_{i-t}, S_{i-t+1},\ldots, S_{i-1})$, the feedback
will compute $S_i$ as given in $(2)$ and so the new state of the LFSR
is $(S_{i-t+1}, S_{i-t+2},\ldots, S_{i-1}, S_i)$.  The *output* of the
LFSR is the symbol falling off the left end and is thus $S_0, S_1, \ldots, S_{n-1}$.

The dsp.SE reader will recognize that if we define polynomials
$$S(z) = S_0 +S_1z + \cdots + S_{n-1}z^{n-1}, ~~ 
\Lambda(z) = 1 + \lambda_1z + \cdots + \lambda_tz^t,$$
then the left side of $(1)$ is the coefficient of $z^i$ in the
product $S(z)\Lambda(z)$. Thus, the product $S(z)\Lambda(z)$
contains no terms of degree $t, t+1, \ldots, n-1$.

Turning to the problem at hand, if the given sequence **can** in fact,
generated by a LFSR of length $L$ (where $L$ is the length of the shortest
LFSR capable of generating $S(z)$), and if $n \geq 2L$, then
the Berlekamp-Massey algorithm will find the feedback coefficients
$\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_L$ of the unknown LFSR as soon
as it has examined the first $2L$ terms $S_0, S_1, \ldots, S_{2L-1}$
of the given sequence. It will then process the remaining terms
$S_{2L}, S_{2L+1}, \ldots, S_{n-1}$ of the sequence, and will discover 
that the same LFSR that it has
already found will generate these remaining terms as well.

It is important to remember that the Berlekamp-Massey algorithm
will find the *shortest* LFSR that will generate 
$(S_0, S_1, \ldots, S_{n-1})$, and this LFSR
might not be the same one
that was *actually* used to generate $(S_0, S_1, \ldots, S_{n-1})$.
Any sequence that can be generated via a LFSR with feedback polynomial
$\Lambda(z)$ can *also* be generated via a (longer) LFSR with feedback
polynomial $\Lambda(z)\Psi(z)$, and the Berlekamp-Massey algorithm
will find the shortest shift register that works.

What if $L$ is such that $2L > N$, then the Berlekamp-Massey
algorithm will find the shortest LFSR that will generate
$(S_0, S_1, \ldots, S_{n-1})$. The length of this LFSR
will generally *not* be $L$ and its feedback coefficients will in
general *not* be the same as those of the actual LFSR
that was used to generate the sequence. If at a later time,
the terms $S_{n}, S_{n+1}, \ldots, S_{2L-1}$ become known,
the algorithm will extend the LFSR and ultimately come up
with the right answer, but for now, it will simply find
the shortest LFSR that will generate
$(S_0, S_1, \ldots, S_{n-1})$.

---

In broad terms, the Kolmogorov-Chaitin theory of complexity
of a sequence
says that for almost all sequences of length $n$, the shortest
program that can print out the sequence has length $n+c$ where
$c$ is a constant. In other words, for most sequences, one can do
little better than simply store the sequence in memory and print it out: there
are no computational methods that will allow you to *generate*
the sequence via calculations. Thus, given an *arbitrary* sequence
of length $n$, the Berlekamp-Massey algorithm will typically
find an LFSR of length $n-1$ that stores the first $n-1$ symbols
and then calculates $S_{n-1}$ via $(2)$ with $t = i = n-1$.

The answer to the OP's question

> "...can the algorithm be used when $2L>N$ and $N$ is "reasonably" close to $2L$?"

is that the algorithm *can* be used, and it *will* find the
shortest LFSR
that will generate  $(S_0, S_1, \ldots, S_{n-1})$, but
this LFSR will typically not be of length $L$ and
the feedback polynomial will typically differ from
that of the LFSR of length $L$ that is known to
generate $(S_0, S_1, \ldots, S_{n-1})$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.. There are still some parts that I don't get though.

You say in your last sentence that this LFSR will typically not be of length L and the feedback polynomial will typically differ from that of the LFSR of length L that is known to generate (S0,S1,…,Sn−1). But doesn't $L$ refer to the shortest LFSR anyway? That's what you say in the beginning too.
Maybe I need to read again 'cause there are lots to absorb but  this part is a bit fuzzy.. Thanks!

Comment: Suppose that the shortest LFSR that generates the sequence $S_0, S_1, \ldots, S_{2L-1}$ is of length $L$. If the Berlekamp-Massey algorithm is given only $S_0, S_1, \ldots, S_{n-1}$ where $n< 2L$, then it will find the shortest LFSR that generates _this_ shorter first part of the whole sequence. Typically, this LFSR will _not_ have length $L$ (the length will typically be smaller than $L$) and the feedback weights will differ, too. Having found this shorter LFSR, if the algorithm is _then_ given $S_n, S_{n+1},\ldots, S_{2L-1}$, it will extend its results and find the actual LFSR of length $L$.

Comment: That's clear; I added an answer with an example demonstrating your answer. If you ever have time you maybe could have a look at my LFSR-related question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295657/are-linear-shift-register-sequences-corresponding-to-reciprocal-polynomials-equi)?

Answer (score 5):

[@Sarwate gave a clear answer.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/6374/12164) I'm just following with an example to demonstrate his answer for the potential benefit of other readers:

Consider the sequence with minimal polynomial $\Lambda(z)=z^6+z^5+z^4+z+1$. With initial state $100111$ this starts as $1001110110000011\dots$ and repeats every $63$ bits ($63$ is its period). So here $L=6$.

- If we try Berlekamp-Massey with the first 12 ($=2L$) or more digits we *do* get the correct minimal polynomial $\Lambda(Z)$, as expected;
- If we input $10$ digits $1001110110$ we are lucky; we get the output $0z^6+z^5+z^3+z+1,\,z^6+z^5+z^2+z+1,\,z^6+z^5+z^4+z+1$. We don't get a unique polynomial because the linear span of $1001110110$ happens to be $6$ and $2\cdot 6 > 10$. However it happens (again, because we are lucky) that we get the correct answer among them. The zero leading coefficient in the first one means that the output bit of the corresponding LFSR is not tapped;
- If we input $11$ digits $10011101100$ then the situation is similar and we get the output $0z^6+z^5+z^3+z+1,\,z^6+z^5+z^2+z+1$. Although the linear span is again $6$, we are not lucky this time and we do not get $\Lambda(z)$ among the output polynomials;
- If we input less than $10$ digits, we don't even get polynomials of degree $6$ so there is no chance we are obtaining $\Lambda(z)$.

So indeed, if we input less than $2L$ terms of the secret sequence, we will not generally obtain the correct linear span or polynomial, although that may happen out of luck.